# How to use array object?

Tags: java

let there is a class named  Calc.java  inside this class there is a method named  Min

```
  public int Min(int one, int two)
    {
        return one - two ;
    }
```

Now in the main class that nemed First.java :

```
package first;
public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calc y [] = new Calc[3];

       System.out.println(y[1].Min(5, 3));
    }
}
```

when Run :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   first.First.main(First.java:9) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total
>   time: 0 seconds)

Netbeans shows Hint : Unbalanced read/write with arrays

i don't know what's wrong !
Thanks...

Comment: Always check the Java tutorials - they are invaluable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: It is not enough to declare an array of a class as new() instance - every member in the array must be created as a new instance

Comment: before print addd `y [1] = new Calc; `

Answer (score 1):

`y[1]` is null, you have to initializes your array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Calc y[] = new Calc[3];
   for(int i=0;i<y.legnth;i++){
       y[i] = new Calc();
   }
   System.out.println(y[1].Min(5, 3));
}
```

Also in Java methods are written starting letter lowerCase. You may interested in this link [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: hmmmm is that Calc y [] = new Calc[3];   mean that he initialize by default?  or i have to declare every array variable?

Comment: @MohamedAnan i don't understand your question, here you are declaring that `y array` stores 3 elements of Calc type, but thehy are not initialized , they are `null`

Comment: @MohamedAnan no... y[0] y[1] y[2] starts in 0.. and y[0] = null by default.. but if u make primitive array like int[] y ; then it's initializate in 0.. cause null is for objects.. you may want to read the link i posted

Comment: @MohamedAnan you don't follow java code conventions.. to others wil be dificuult to understand your code

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the calc object before using it.  It is not enough to initialize the array itself, but you have to initialize the calc objects in the array like this:

```
calc[1]=new calc();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first line in your main method, when you are doing

```
Calc y [] = new Calc[3];
```

the values of the array will be,

```
y[0]=null, y[1]=null, y[2]=null
```

Why?

Because like when you create an integer, int[] the array is initialized with default values(i.e zero), similarly when an object array is created, it is initialized with null by default.

Now before doing any operation on an array Item, you have to create the object.

so you should do,

```
y[1] = new Calc();
```

before calling the Min method.

I hope this made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating an array there? Is it really needed? And if at all it is needed, you need to populate that array with `Calc` object first before invoking any instance method.

---

But, it seems like, your method should be `public static`, given that `Calc` class is just a utility class, and `Min` method is not at all associated with any instance, rather just with that class. So, modify it so:

```
public static int min(int one, int two)
```

And then you can just invoke this method on class name:

```
Calc.min(5, 3);
```

No need to have different instances of that class. Also take a look at the [API of `Math` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) which has similar utility methods. You will get an idea of what I'm talking about.

Moreover, your `min` method doesn't seem to do what it should do. For e.g., `y[i].Min(5, 3)` will currently return `2`. Strange isn't it? It is not at all returning the minimum of the passed arguments. You should change the `return` statement to:

```
return one < two ? one : two;
```

If you understand this, you should further extend it to consider equal numbers.

Comment: Woow it work...... actually I'm a beginner java programmer  and this is is a test my new lesson>>>> thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Calc y [] = new Calc[3];
for (int i = 0; i< 3;i++)
{
    y[i] = new Calc();
}
```